# Google Apps Script. Why last element of bullet list is partial?

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't understand one thing about bullet lists in apps script. So I have really simple bullet list with several item, after I inserted last element I pressed return twice to go to new line and end list. But the problem is when I create named range and then call method [isPartial()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element?hl=en#isPartial()) on the range elements, last one returns `true`, it has type `TEXT` and has a parent with type `LIST_ITEM`, while previous items of list already has type `LIST_ITEM` and are not partial.
Here is the example text:
[image]

I'm checking partial range element in this way:
function checkIfRangesIsPartial() {

```
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  const ranges = doc.getNamedRanges();

  ranges.forEach(item => {
    item.getRange().getRangeElements().forEach(element => {

      if (element.isPartial()) {
        Logger.log(element.getElement().getParent().getType()) // LIST_ITEM
        Logger.log(element.getElement().asText().getText());  //'5'
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I'm adding named range in this way:

```
  function addNamedRange(rangeLabel) {
    const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    const selectedElements = doc.getSelection();

    doc.addNamedRange(rangeLabel, selectedElements);
  }
```

How can I avoid this problem?
Would appreciate any advice)

**UPD**: Tried to create named range via [RangeBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-builder?hl=en) so when it comes to last element of list I add element's parent instead of actual element in next way:

```
 function addBulletListToRange() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  const selectedElements = doc.getSelection().getRangeElements();

  const rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();

  [...selectedElements].forEach(item => {
      const element = item.getElement();
      const elementType = element.getType();
      let rangeElement;

      if (elementType === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH
          || elementType === DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
        rangeElement = element;
      } else if (elementType !== DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM && element.getParent().getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
        rangeElement = element.getParent();
      }
      
      rangeBuilder.addElement(rangeElement);
  });

  doc.addNamedRange('test', rangeBuilder.build());
}
```

It seems to solve the problem, but I still don't understand why it happens, list should be complete and doesn't have partial elements since I'm on the new line and visually list is over.

Comment: Could you please provide some example code and a screenshot of the document ? Just some mock data that replicates your issue.

Comment: Hey, updated description. In one of the places of application which I'm working with there is a check if any of elements of named range is partial it throws exception, so I'm trying to figure out why last element of list is partial and how to avoid it.

Comment: can you also provide details on how you set up the named ranges and the code you used? as far as I know you can't create name ranges in the UI itself.

Comment: Updated description